# Graph Layout for 256 vertices and 2048 edges - Untangle

Tags: graph, nodes, gephi, vertices, edges

I am trying to create a graph with about 256 edges and 2048 vertices. In almost all layouts I tried in Gephi, I get a bundles mass of wires. Is there any layout or software that can distribute the nodes spatially and minimize the edges crossings?

Comment: Have you tried graphviz which uses the dot language as input?

Comment: No, but from what I know graphviz doesn't do well with large graphs. But I'll take a shot at it. Thanks.

Comment: You have to select the right layout engine. See http://www.graphviz.org/content/hierachical-graph-max-number-nodesedges